# Can I call another PHP script and pass $_GET variables?

Tags: php, jquery

I currently call a PHP script from javascript and return the json data.  This works great from the client. I need to make the same call to the PHP script from inside another PHP file.  Can this be done?

My current jquery call looks like this:

```
$.post('functions/get_testdata.php?type='+Type, function(data) {
   ....
});
```

From inside another PHP script I'd like to call:

```
'functions/get_testdata.php?type='.$type
```

I could just copy the contents of get_testdata to my other PHP page but I'd like to maintain just one code block for this.

Any thoughts or am I missing the obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You could use something like cURL to do what you want to do, however I would suggest that a better approach might be to encapsulate the logic on that page into a class or function.  So that when you call that page you might do something like

```
$type = $_GET['type'];

$result = your_new_function($type);
```

You could then call this new function (or class) from anywhere in your code and just pass it the parameter you want.

Answer (score 0):

$_GET is global so you would have access to it in all php files. You would just have to include the other file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php